# Отправка данных через html форму в MySQL

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется WAMP сервер, файл index.php в котором содержится код:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="bd1.php">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя"/>
        <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="Текст"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

и файл bd1.php в котором содержится код

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'])) {

    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "rf", "3306");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "провал" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES (`name`, `text`);";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

    if ($result1 = 'true') {
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    } else {
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  cat;"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>N</th>';
    echo '<th>Ник</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['vid'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
 mysql_close($connect_to_db);
?>
```

Загвоздка заключается в том что данные, переданные через форму не попадают в базу данных. Сообщение об ошибке не выводится. Пишется что: "Информация занесена в базу данных" и таблица с данными уже существующими в ней, занесенными через phpMyAdmin вручную. Подскажите, где я допустил неточность.

P.S. Если в строке

$query1 = "INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES (`name`, `text`);";

вставить скажем цифры, вместо глобальных переменных, то информация попадет в БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вам синтаксис учить надо и основы PHP.

Вам нужно данные с `$_POST` сохранять, но сначала хотя бы немного защиты:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ($name, $text);";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
```

Но лучше сразу советую переходить на PDO.

Comment: Да, вы правы насчет синтаксиса. Я действительно плохо разбираюсь. Ваш совет помог, спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрБолдырев поищите примеры простые как обрабатывают данные с формы и желательно примеры с ООП стилем, а не процедурным.

Comment: Хорошо я обязательно поищу. Я еще не дошел до изучения ООП. Пока практикуюсь.

Comment: @АлександрБолдырев тогда это пока не критично, для познавания азов сойдет и процедурный.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут вам необходимо передать полученные данные:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES (`name`, `text`);";
```

Это можно сделать так:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$query1 = "INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ($name, $text);";
```